# Updating another table based when the arrival date is today

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

Ok so i have `warehouse` table which contains a field `quantity`

I have another table of `OrderArrival` that contains a field `arrivaldate`

I want that when the arrivaldate is today the quantity field must be updated in warehouse table by some value.

I thought of using triggers but then i remembered they can only be used in response to CRUD events.

Is there any other way i can do this or am i missing something in the triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever code that populates the `OrderArrival` table, could this be amended to also write to the `warehouse` table based on the logic of `arrivaldate` = `sysdate`?

Comment: sorry not following you.

Comment: @WinCoder - what code populates the OrderArrival table? ie: what code contains the call to the INSERT statement to add the row to the table? A stored procedure? PHP? Java? Something else?

Comment: So within the code that adds the row to the OrderArrival table, could you not also increment the quantity value in the warehouse table if the arrivaldate = sysdate?

Comment: well i could but then i would have to make a new thread just to deal with this single case, and there are other numerous cases in my db.

Comment: @WinCoder, maybe I mis-read your question - are you looking for a scheduled job that looks at the OrderArrival table and counts the number of items with an arrivaledate of today and then places that value in the quantity field in the warehouse table? If so, you could look at SQL Server Jobs - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx - and create a daily job that runs a stored procedure to update the quantity field

Comment: you are dead right. unfortunately i am using the express edition of sql server and after i did a bit of research it turns out jobs are not available in this edition. I am too far out in the database to change versions now. I think i'll go with your original suggestion of handling this in application layer.

Comment: Thanks @WinCoder - could you tick my answer as the correct one (does wonders for one's reputation!) :-)  Best of luck getting it sorted in the application layer